# PHP JSON vs MySQL JSON Extra Space Between key:value

Tags: php, mysql, json

Using PHP 7.2 and MySQL 5.7

When I convert an array into json in php there are no spaces between values but when it's insert into MySQL JSON column there is a space after the ":". PHP and MySQL say they are using RFC 7159.

PHP- `{"MYKEY":"MYVALUE"}`

MySQL- `{"MYKEY": "MYVALUE"}`

Is there a setting in either php or mysql to standardized them so they produce the same result. I have some automated checks that detect changes to values to record in logs as changed values and it's flagging every update because the php produced values never matches the mysql version. I can decode the mysql value in php then encode it back to json to get a match but that seems like a really poor way to handle it, but it'll work if nothing else comes up. Thanks!

Comment: The amount of whitespace does not matter (in accordance with the RFC). This is not python. You need to find another way to match the json data, or not store as json in the first place.

Comment: @SalmanA Thanks, as mentioned I can match it by just re-encoding the data into php from the mysql data just figured there might be an easier (or cleaner) solution like a setting or something I didn't know about.

Comment: You can use json_table on your column AND the input json, then use sql operations on the two sets e.g. the `except` operation returns null.

Comment: Maybe you can save it as TEXT. If you need some JSON actions on it, then you can CAST it to json.

Comment: I do use mysql json functions on it more often then this one situation so as of now just decoding the mysql json and encoding it in php before checking the 2 values seems to be the best way for this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL stores JSON value in a binary format not as a string.

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  Data Types  /  The JSON Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html)

So when you get that value you just get its presentation. If you need to check if there is a change, you may need to store your JSON data as string in addition to a JSON field (which requires more space).

Or better calculate a hash value (SHA1 or MD5 is just fine in this case) and compare just the hash to detect any change.

Comment: What if json being hashed is {a:1, b:2) and json being tested is {b:2, a:1}

Comment: @SalmanA https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization

Comment: @sam you could post that as answer.

Comment: I mean calculate the hash value from the PHP side, insert the JSON and that hash value into DB, and then compare the hash from the DB and the calculated hash value from the PHP side again.
So it is very unlikely you to have `{a:1, b:2}` and then `{b:2, a:1}` for the same data.
But canonicalization is good anyway.